# List of DbConnection.GetSchema collection names?

Tags: ado.net

When you call DbConnection.GetSchema you give it the string name of a collection you are interested in. I can't find a list of collections anywhere. Is the list of collections immutable or does it vary by database type (orcle, sql server, etc.)?

I'm interested in getting a list of all collection names in a few database types such as sql server, and sqlite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use an OleDbConnection even if I'm connecting with Oracle, Sql Server... Then I can use:

```
myOleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemGuid.Tables);
```

Possible values for OleDbSchemaGuid: 
(note that depending of the database some of these can throw a NotSupported Exception:

```
OleDbSchemaGuid.Assertions;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Catalogs;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Character_Sets;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Check_Constraints;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Check_Constraints_By_Table;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Collations;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Column_Domain_Usage;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Column_Privileges;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Constraint_Column_Usage;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Constraint_Table_Usage;
OleDbSchemaGuid.DbInfoKeywords;
OleDbSchemaGuid.DbInfoLiterals;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Foreign_Keys;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Indexes;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Key_Column_Usage;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Primary_Keys;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedure_Columns;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedure_Parameters;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedures;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Provider_Types;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Referential_Constraints;
OleDbSchemaGuid.SchemaGuids;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Schemata;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Sql_Languages;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Statistics;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Table_Constraints;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Table_Privileges;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Table_Statistics;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables_Info;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Translations;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Trustee;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Usage_Privileges;
OleDbSchemaGuid.View_Column_Usage;
OleDbSchemaGuid.View_Table_Usage;
OleDbSchemaGuid.Views;
```

Comment: `GetSchema()` only accepts a parameter of a type `string`. I'd say you must have confused it with `GetOleDbSchemaTable()`

Answer (score 4):

The list varies by provider. For this reason, some [Common Schema Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254501.aspx) have been defined, that are always available regardless of the provider. One of them is the MetaDataCollections collection, which will return a DataTable with a list of the supported schema collections for the current provider, the number of restrictions that they each support, and the number of identifier parts that they use.

Answer (score 2):

For System.Data.SQLite I finally found what is supported:

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/readme.htm

"DbConnection.GetSchema(...) support includes ReservedWords, MetaDataCollections, DataSourceInformation, DataTypes, Columns, Tables, Views, ViewColumns, Catalogs, Indexes, IndexColumns, ForeignKeys and Triggers. "

I think sql server would be about the same, but I still have no definitive list.

Comment: That's an old link... the current version can be found at http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/features.wiki

Answer (score 2):

The list that you are talking about is called [MetaDataCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/common-schema-collections#metadatacollections). If you call [GetSchema()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema?view=netframework-4.7.1) without any parameters, it will give you a list of all the collection names that you can use.

Also, there is a fixed list of collection names that are [common](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/common-schema-collections) to all databases. Some of ADO.NET providers will add additional parameters specific to the database that your are connecting too.

For example, ODP.NET will add collection name called Users that will give you all the users (schemas) available in the Oracle Database.